# Why is there a difference in these For loops?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, factorial

When finding the factorial of a number this loops one more time

```
var factorial = function(n) {
var result = 1;
for(var i = 1;i<=n;i++){
    result *= i;
}

return result;
```

};

Than this code

```
var factorial = function(n) {
var result = 1;
for(var i = 1;i<n;i++){
    result *= i;
}

return result;
```

};

Why is this? As i increases will it not be less than or equal to at the same time as it is less than?

Comment: The second one returns the wrong answer.

Comment: @NetMage Why does it return the wrong answer

Comment: Imagine you call `factorial1(3)` - how many times will it loop? What will `result` be? Do the same thing for `factorial2(3)` and see what happens.

Comment: @JerryMurphy it returns the wrong answer because you miss an iteration in the second loop, because it terminates earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n = 2`

Ok.

Now, which of these is true (or both of them)?

`2<=n`

Or

`2<n`

Comment: but i is starting at less than 2 so increases why is the loop terminating at a different point

Comment: Yes... it starts at 1. The first one will stop at 2. The second one will stop at 1. Because 2 is less than or equal to 2. And 2 is not less than 2.

Comment: @AmirAfghani Downvote was before correction in post.

Comment: @NetMage yeah, sorry. On my phone so editing and typing is not easy. Haha

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

> As i increases will it not be less than or equal to at the same time
>   as it is less than?

No, for example, if i = 5, and n = 5:

```
i < n  FALSE

i <= n TRUE
```